# Radio button list and label not lining up

Tags: css, forms, radio-button

I've got a complex form with rather a lot of css on the following page.  Most things are lining up the way I would like, but if you scroll down to "Membership Type" you'll see that the label and radio button lists are not lined up nicely like everything else is.  I thought at first that perhaps the required asterisk was pushing things down, but I removed it and that didn't seem to be the case.  Ideas?  THank you.

http://www.craftonhills.edu/Student_Resources/Student_Life/Clubs/Alpha_Gamma_Sigma/Membership_Application.aspx

Comment: what browser are you testing in? It appears to be spaced evenly in Firefox

Comment: dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the css on line 829 on screen.css with below css

```
.scfForm ul {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the radio has default margins. I tried this in google chrome and it pushed the radio button up slightly

```
#form_767FC5570C444D6F977241A501F3C667_field_EB23079082B64C4F91BAD9F0444872DAscope_0 {
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```